# How to inject a constraint into a $ref object in jsonSchema

Tags: jsonschema

Consider the following snippet of jsonSchema

```
"properties": {
    "custom-range": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/minMax",
        "description": "Custom range of allowable values",
    }
},
```

with the $defs section being...

```
"$defs": {
    "minMax": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "min": {
                "type": "number",
                "description": "Minimum value"
            },
            "max": {
                "type": "number",
                "description": "Maximum value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to restrict instance/values of the "custom-range" instances of minMax.min and minMax.max?

So for example I would like to restrict minMax.min with "minimum":20,"maximum":30 for the "custom-range" instance of that object.

ANSWER: Thank you user gregsdennis

The solution that seems to work is as follows

```
"properties": {
    "custom-range": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/minMax",
        "description": "Custom range of allowable values",
        "properties": {
            "min": {
                "minimum": 20,
                "maximum": 30
            }
        }
    }
},
```

When used as the schema for a jsonschema command line validator, I was able to get a message of "100.0: 100.0 is greater than the maximum of 30"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.  It looks like you've answered your own question: just add `minimum:20` and `maximum: 30` to the `minMax.min` definition.

Comment: there could be multiple instances of the minMax object.  for example there could be an entry in "properties" called "custom-range-2" that is also a minMax that might need different restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to define a subschema that just declares the min/max values, and then combine that with a `$ref` to the definition in an `allOf`.

```json
"properties": {
  "custom-range": {
    "allOf": [
      { "$ref": "#/$defs/minMax" },
      {
        "properties": {
          "min": { "minimum": 20 },
          "max": { "maximum": 50 }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "custom-range-2": {
    "allOf": [
      { "$ref": "#/$defs/minMax" },
      {
        "properties": {
          "min": { "minimum": -5 },
          "max": { "maximum": 100 }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This works because JSON Schema is just a bunch of constraints.  The `$ref` to the `minMax` definition ensures that you have an object with the appropriate properties, and the secondary subschema in the `allOf` simply adds more requirements to those same properties.

It's not "injecting" the values into the definition so much as adding the constraints alongside the definition.

Comment: Your answer led me to my answer that works according to the command line jsonschema.  Just add the "properties" subsection you have at the same level of the "$ref" in the definition of the "custom-range" property, and boom, I get "100.0: 100.0 is greater than the maximum of 30" Thank you sir

Comment: That actually shouldn't work.  In draft 4 you need the `allOf` with the `$ref` in a subschema by itself.  The JSON Schema specification states that if `$ref` is present, all other keywords MUST be ignored.  I suspect the implementation you're using has a bug.